# Infant visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, children

I have a UK tier 4 visa and applied for my 8 month as a dependant but was refused. Can I get my infant to come up on a visitor visa for 6 months?

Comment: Why was your child's visa refused?

Comment: @Samantha Julie Travelling alone? Where is your child now and who is caring for them while you are studying in the UK? How will you support your child in the UK?

Comment: Refused because they want me to apply with husband. Said I never proved that I've cared for for child on my own.  I planned to get a nursery + a childminder when studying. I met the financial requirements that they asked for. Husband must stay with our elder second child of 9 years.

Comment: @Samantha Julie It seems very unlikely that a Visit visa would be approved given the circumstances you describe- the ECO would almost certainly not find an intention to return home credible. Your best option is probably to consult an Immigration lawyer for advice.

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer.

Comment: Circumstances? Please elaborate...is it Because in travelling with an 8 month old, alone, without my husband? Surely now, both children will still be alone with one parent... Didn't understand why they didnt at least grant the youngest the visa approval...

Comment: Note: your infant could also be a reason you got your visa (you will return home as soon as possible, after study).

Answer (score 2):

Having been refused a Dependent visa it’s likely that a Visit visa application would also be refused because the ECO would almost certainly not find an intention to return home credible. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules Your best option is probably to consult an Immigration lawyer.